# private and public operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I tried to implement the method of Horner and faced a problem:

```
root@host:~# cat | g++ -x c++ -std=gnu++11 - && ./a.out
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

#include <cstdlib>

template< typename F >
class horner
{
public :

    typedef std::vector< F > V;

    horner(F const & x_, V const & c_)
        : x(x_)
        , c(c_)
        , y(0.0L)
    { ; }

    operator F const () const
    {
        return std::accumulate(c.rbegin(), c.rend(), *this).y;
    }

private :

    friend horner std::accumulate< typename V::const_reverse_iterator, horner >(typename V::const_reverse_iterator, typename V::const_reverse_iterator, horner);

    void operator = (F const & rhs)
    {
        y = rhs;
    }

    operator F ()
    {
        y *= x;
        return y;
    }

    F const & x;
    V const & c;
    F y;

};

#define N_COEFF_PARABOLA 3

int main()
{
    typedef double F;
    typedef typename horner< F >::V V;

    V c;
    unsigned seed(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
    std::cout << "seed = 0x"
              << std::uppercase << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(sizeof(seed) * 2)
              << seed << std::endl;
    std::mt19937 generator(seed);
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(c), N_COEFF_PARABOLA, generator);

    std::cout << "coefficients: ";
    std::copy(c.begin(), c.end(), std::ostream_iterator< F >(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << ';' << std::endl;

    F const x(generator());
    F const y(horner< F >(x, c));
    std::cout << "y(" << x << ") = " << y << std::endl;

    // naive
    F xx(1.0L);
    F yy(0.0L);
    for (typename V::size_type i(0); i < c.size(); ++i) {
        yy += c[i] * xx;
        xx *= x;
    }
    std::cout << "y'(" << x << ") = " << yy << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
// press ^D

<stdin>: In function ‘int main()’:
<stdin>:39:5: error: ‘horner<F>::operator F() [with F = double]’ is private
<stdin>:71:32: error: within this context
root@host:~#
```

In my view the problem should not arise, since `main()` only sees `operator F const & () const` version of the type conversion operator. But it is.

What is the reason of the error?

Comment: Overload resolution does not care about access specifiers.

Comment: Indeed, because they're not a part of a method signature.

Answer (score 4):

The concepts of visibility and accessibility are completely orthogonal in C++. If a method is visible, but not accessible, the compiler may select it in overload resolution and produce a hard error because it can't use it. This is done on purpose so code does not change semantics silently when it gains or looses access.

Comment: I ran into this recently, and it's frustrating me. All I want is to have one overloaded variant be accessible privately (so it can give non-const references), and the other overloaded variant be const and public (so that public code can't change the references). Why isn't this allowed?

Comment: @Tynach, because if it was allowed, you'd use it and then two years later you'd be wondering why the hell does the same function, with the same type of argument, behaves differently depending on whether it is called from another method of the same class or from code outside that class.

Comment: at which point I'd look at the header and see the two declarations being in public/private and I'd already have my answer. To me that's a poor excuse.